# Unable to start database in glassfish in CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos, database, oracle-database

Environment: VPS, CentOS7, glassfish3, server is running.

Tried: both in root and glassfish user. a comamnd: "startNetworkServer"
and `sudo netstat -lntp | grep 1527` nothing happened so it seems port is free.

goal: to start database in glassfish server

I searched over and over but couldnt find any solution. I am trying to deploy my web app on glassfish server in CentOS7. As my web app uses databases, i have to start a database so i hit this command in "bin" directory,

```
./asadmin start-database
```

but i get

> Starting database in Network Server mode on host 0.0.0.0 and port 1527. Unable to start database. Please check log in /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/databases/derby.log. Command start-database failed.

I dont understand why i get this error. when i see derby.log, nothing was written. I am completely stuck now. I hope I can get your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

glassfish3 was causing this problem. i installed 4 and worked well.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer.